# Error al conectarme a DB2 por Python

Tags: python-3.7, db2

Estoy intentando conectarme a una base de datos DB2 desde python. Para ello estoy usando el paquete `ibm_db_dbi`.

El problema es que cuando intento hacer la conexión, me sale el siguiente error:

```
ibm_db_dbi.ProgrammingError: ibm_db_dbi::ProgrammingError: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30073N  "0x2110" Parameter value "0x0000" is not supported.  SQLSTATE=58017\r SQLCODE=-30073
```

La conexión la tengo de la siguiente manera:

```
import ibm_db_dbi as db

conn = db.connect("DATABASE=miDB;HOSTNAME=miHost;PORT=miPuerto;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=user;PWD=pass;", "", "")
```

¿Alguien sabe cuál es el problema?

P.D.: También he probado a especificar el driver, pero sigue en las mismas.

Comment: A lo que estoy viendo es que los detalles de su sistema operativo (versión + nombre), su versión y bitness de Python, la salida de texto sin formato de `pip freeze` (o `pip3 freeze` dependiendo de sus versiones), y si puede para conectarse a la misma base de datos con las mismas credenciales de conexión a través de la CLI (con el comando `db2cli validate -dsn xxx -user yyy -passwd zzz` después de crear los detalles de dsn en el `db2dsdriver.cfg` archivo xml de acuerdo con la documentación)

Comment: También recuerde que en su cadena de conexión, los valores de los parámetros (por ejemplo, myDB, myHost, myPort, UID, PWD) deben ser correctos, por lo que siempre es útil imprimir su cadena de conexión antes de conectarse, para validarlo es lo que asume que sea.